# how to render javascript in update action with jQuery-File-Upload and Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-file-upload

I'm using [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which allows for AJAX-y file uploads.  I'm using it for users to change their avatar image without having the entire page reload.  This is covered in RailsCast 381 but I cannot get it to work.  The user can do this in the edit/update actions by choosing a new file to upload. This happens at `authors/:id/edit`

My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#image-form').fileupload();
});
```

I watch the Network tab inside Chrome and when I "Choose File" a POST action is fired which runs the "authors#update" action.  Inside which I have this code:

```
@author.update(author_params)
```

The update code updates the image file in my database.  Inside `update.js.erb` I tried to put the following code:

```
$('#image').html("<%= @author.image_url %>");
```

But it never executes.  I know the code inside the update action executes because when I refresh the page at `authors/:id/edit` the new image appears.  But I want it to happen on the fly.  But I just can't figure out why `update.js.erb` is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Rails was wrapping the javascript response in a layout.  The solution was the following inside my update action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render layout: false }
end
```